# PyQT Attach/drag one window with another PyQT window... - same program

Tags: python, pyqt, window, pyqt4

So here is the deal... I have 1 "AA" window. I click button I get another "BB " window next to it using...

```
    a = str(self.geometry())
    a= a.strip("PyQt4.QtCore.QRect(").strip(")").replace(" ","").split(",")
    UI.setGeometry(int(a[0])+520,int(a[1]),700,900)
```

Now in the new "BB" window I would like to click checkbox that would say "Link to main "AA" window"(I can implement that just need the function/signal to get mouse/window drag info...). Meaning that when I move main "AA" window to the left by 100 pixels I would like my new "BB " window to move to left as well... Can any one help me with it? 
I believe that I need signal with mouse/movement click not sure I'm lost here :- (

Hope this make some sort of sense.
Dariusz

Edit1
Further down the line I managed too get some cords using :

```
def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    print QMouseEvent.pos()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    cursor =QtGui.QCursor()
    print cursor.pos()
```

Sadly I don't get any cords when I drag/move window nor have a way to tell if I'm dragging the window or just mouse across ui... Tricky. I have an alternative to do it but it involves redoing the frame system but thats a bit of a pain, was hoping there is still a way around it...

Comment: That is some fugly, hacky, string processing you got going on there.

Comment: Yeah did it long time ago, need to revisit it an do it properly I think... still learning :- )

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how it could be done.  It depends a bit on whether you want relative movements or absolute positioning (this currently does relative movements).

Basically, you just need to override the `moveEvent` of your main window.  This normally gets called when the user finishes the window move.  Then you can decide which sub-windows need to be repositioned.

Also, I added a much better way of duplicating a window's geometry that doesn't require super-string-hackiness.

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui



class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui_lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.ui_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui_widget)
        self.ui_widget.setLayout(self.ui_lay)
        self.ui_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Create Window', self)
        self.ui_lay.addWidget(self.ui_btn)
        self.ui_btn.clicked.connect(self.create_window)
        self.other_window = None

    def create_window(self):
        self.other_window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        self.other_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self.other_window)
        self.other_window.setCentralWidget(self.other_widget)
        self.other_lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.other_widget.setLayout(self.other_lay)
        self.ui_chk = QtGui.QCheckBox('Link', self.other_window)
        self.other_lay.addWidget(self.ui_chk)
        self.other_window.show()
        self.position_other_window()

    def position_other_window(self):
        geo = self.geometry()
        geo.moveLeft(geo.left() + geo.width() + 10)
        self.other_window.setGeometry(geo)


    def moveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyWindow, self).moveEvent(event)
        print 'HERE', time.time()
        if self.other_window and self.ui_chk.isChecked():
            #self.position_other_window()
            diff = event.pos() - event.oldPos()
            geo = self.other_window.geometry()
            geo.moveTopLeft(geo.topLeft() + diff)
            self.other_window.setGeometry(geo)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Omg there was moveEvent signal! Ahhh snap thanks! I knew  I dig in too deep with mousePressEvent signal and I should look for something else. Anyway thanks! This does exactly what I want !